# How to print to html with express node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

How does one display text held in a variable on the server side node.js in html.

In other words, just to be doubly clear, I have output pulled from an api that accesses twitter (Twitt) and I am trying to display that text at the bottom of the page.

This is how the webpage is called

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./Homepage.html');
});
```

This is where the Node.js files are called:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
```

And here is where the variable is:

```
T.get('search/tweets', { q: hash1 + ' since:2013-11-11', count: 5 },
    function(err, reply) {
        response = (reply),
        console.log(response)
        app.append(response)
    })
```

Comment: I don't understand exactly where your call to ``T`` is. You will need to call that from within your express route to be able to send its output with your response.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the code to inject on the page will change on every request, you should have the code more or less as follows:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res){

  // make the call to twitter before sending the response
  var options = { q: hash1 + ' since:2013-11-11', count: 5 };
  T.get('search/tweets', options, function(err, reply) {
    // use RENDER instead of SENDFILE
    res.render('./Homepage.html', {data: reply});
  });

});
```

Notice how (1) I am making the call to Twitter inside the request, (2) I am using res.render() (http://expressjs.com/api.html#res.render) rather than res.sendFile().

This way, your view (homepage.html) can inject the data passed to res.render(). Depending on the template engine that you are using the syntax might be different, but if you are using [EJS](https://github.com/visionmedia/ejs) the following should work:

```
<p>your html goes here</p>
<p>The data from Twitter was <h2><%= data %></h2></p>
<p>xxx</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use something like ejs templating.

For example, in app.js you will have:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.render('index', {base: req.protocol + "://" + req.headers.host});
});
```

And then inside index.ejs you will have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Websitename</title>
  <base href="<%- base %>">
</head>
```

Make sure to set your view engine like so near the top of app.js

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```