# load variables saved from a html form using an app.js in the next loading .html

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

I am expanding Node.js and using them alongside HTML files.

However, I am unable to figure the following.

I build a `form.html` where variables such as `firstName`, `lastName` can be gathered. The formed is filled, and the bottom is pressed, and it executes an app.js with an `action = "/signup"`.

The `action` is followed by the following app.js containing:

```
// Bodyparser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Static folder
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//signup route
app.post('/signup', (req, res){
//Processes including storing data into mailchimp and mongodb
});
```

Now after the process is performed a new HTML file will be open, `success.html`.

In `success.html` I wish to create a custom message with some of the variables gathered from the previous processes from `form.html`.

`<p>Sample text <h1><%= name %></h1> sample text</p>`

I have tried solutions suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412372/how-to-print-to-html-with-express-node-js) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37991995/passing-a-variable-from-node-js-to-html) and other options. I even tried changing to `action = "file.php"` and then executing two `.php` files with different `<form action="">` and it has not work.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you're using EJS notation in your `success.html`. In that case you can just `res.render` the file.

You can see [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) how can you use EJS with Express. But once you created the `success.ejs` file (most probably in your case changing the extension will do)

Then you can just do instead of `res.sendFile`:

```
res.render('success', {
        name: firstName + " " + lastName
});
```

Comment: Thank you and I will have a look into it. However, is there another way to achieve it? I am trying to execute everything within `app.post('/signup', (req, res){});`

Comment: you will execute this inside `app.post('/signup', (req, res){... });` instead of `res.send` or `res.json` you are using `res.render` which is the standard way to render a view.